# how to form an http post by python requests package

Tags: python, python-requests

The doc is here: https://www.deepl.com/docs-api/translating-text/example/

POST /v2/translate?auth_key=[yourAuthKey]> HTTP/1.0

Host: api.deepl.com

User-Agent: YourApp

Accept: */*

Content-Length: 54

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

auth_key=[yourAuthKey]&text=Hello, world&target_lang=DE

How should I form the calling for python requests package? The following seems to be wrong. Thank you.

```
import requests
r = requests.post("https://api.deepl.com", data={"Content-Length": 54, "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "User-Agent": "YourApp", "auth_key": "XXXXXXXXXX&text=Hello, world&target_lang=DE"})
```

Comment: instead of data=... try headers=... See if that works. If it does then I will create an answer for that :) However the part with auth, seems like you will need to put it as a params and not in headers

Comment: Sadly still not working. The code looks like this right now.
`import requests
r = requests.post("https://api.deepl.com", headers={"Content-Length": "54", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "User-Agent": "YourApp", "Accept": "*/*"}, params={"auth_key": "XXXXXXXX&text=Hello, world&target_lang=DE"})
print(r.status_code, r.reason)`

Comment: You are doing it wrong, try to modify this: ```import requests r = requests.post("https://api.deepl.com", headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "User-Agent": "#ADD REAL USER AGENT HERE", "Accept": "*/*"}, params={"auth_key": "XXXXXXXX", "text": "hello", "world&target_lang": "DE"}) print(r.status_code, r.reason)``` however there is something missing in your question and I do not believe you posted a correct request but modified it with uncorrectly. Would be easier if you showed a real example.

Comment: I know. Thanks for your patience but still not working. I am confused as well. The doc is here https://www.deepl.com/docs-api/translating-text/example/
`import requests 
r = requests.post("https://api.deepl.com", headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "User-Agent": "NodePing", "Accept": "*/*"}, params={"auth_key": "XXXXX", "text": "hello world", "target_lang": "DE"}) 
print(r.status_code, r.reason)`

Answer (score 2):

the curl example from the docs, [translated to requests](https://curl.trillworks.com/).

```
import requests

data = {'auth_key': 'yourAuthKey',
        'text': 'Hello, world',
        'target_lang': 'DE'}

response = requests.post('https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate', data=data)
```

If you want to add extra info like `User-Agent`, `Content-Type`, etc. then pass them in `headers` argument as dict.